# ¿Por qué replace no funciona de forma correcta?

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de hacer una pequeña prueba de *Syntax Highlighting*

Defino una constante `reserved` que contiene un objeto, en el cual pongo el texto plano a colorear y luego el HTML coloreado con algunas reglas de CSS

Hago un `for` para recorrer el objeto, y luego un `replace`, sin embargo, no está funcionando correctamente

Obtengo este HTML:

```
<span class="<span">"token-reserved"&gt;let</span> abc = ""
```

**Este es mi código**

```js
const reserved = {
    ":":"<span class='token-assing'>:</span>",
    "}":"<span class='token-assing'>}</span>",
    "{":"<span class='token-assing'>{</span>",
    ":":"<span class='token-assing'>:</span>",
    "let":"<span class='token-reserved'>let</span>",
    "var":"<span class='token-reserved'>var</span>",
    "const":"<span class='token-reserved'>const</span>",
    "false":"<span class='token-bool'>false</span>",
    "true":"<span class='token-bool'>true</span>",
    '"':"<span class='token-str'>&quot;",

};

const elems = document.querySelectorAll(".language-javascript");

const initTokenization = () => {
    elems.forEach(el => {
        for(indexName in reserved) {
            el.querySelector("code").innerHTML = el.querySelector("code").innerHTML.replace(indexName, reserved[indexName]);
        }
    });
};

initTokenization();
```

```css
.token-assing {
    color: rgb(255, 212, 132);
}

.token-reserved {
    color: rgb(196, 132, 255);
}

.token-bool {
    color: rgb(255, 132, 132);
}

.token-str {
    color: rgb(132, 255, 138);
}
```

```html
<pre class="language-javascript"><code>let</code></pre>
```

Y lo que quiero obtener sería algo así

```css
.token-reserved {
    color: rgb(196, 132, 255);
}
```

```html
<pre class="language-javascript"><code><span class="token-reserved">let</span></code></pre>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando accedes al HTML interno, aunque definas las comillas de los atributos como apostrofes (`'`) se van a convertir en comillas completas (`"`), esto hace que se reemplacen y deformen el HTML final.

```js
console.dir(document.getElementById("container").innerHTML);
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div id='prueba'> Tengo un id con comillas simples '</div>
</div>
```

Esto también podemos comprobarlo si eliminamos las comillas de la lista de reservados:

```js
const reserved = {
    ":":"<span class='token-assing'>:</span>",
    "}":"<span class='token-assing'>}</span>",
    "{":"<span class='token-assing'>{</span>",
    ":":"<span class='token-assing'>:</span>",
    "let":"<span class='token-reserved'>let</span>",
    "var":"<span class='token-reserved'>var</span>",
    "const":"<span class='token-reserved'>const</span>",
    "false":"<span class='token-bool'>false</span>",
    "true":"<span class='token-bool'>true</span>",

};

const elems = document.querySelectorAll(".language-javascript");

const initTokenization = () => {
    elems.forEach(el => {
        for(indexName in reserved) {
            el.querySelector("code").innerHTML = el.querySelector("code").innerHTML.replace(indexName, reserved[indexName]);
        }
    });
};

initTokenization();
```

```css
.token-assing {
    color: rgb(255, 212, 132);
}

.token-reserved {
    color: rgb(196, 132, 255);
}

.token-bool {
    color: rgb(255, 132, 132);
}

.token-str {
    color: rgb(132, 255, 138);
}
```

```html
<pre class="language-javascript"><code>let</code></pre>
```

Para este caso en especifico bastaría con cambiar el orden de la tokenización, sin embargo, no creo que sea la solución correcta porque va a fallar si ya existen elementos dentro de tu contenedor padre:

```js
const reserved = {
    '"':"<span class='token-str'>&quot;",
    ":":"<span class='token-assing'>:</span>",
    "}":"<span class='token-assing'>}</span>",
    "{":"<span class='token-assing'>{</span>",
    ":":"<span class='token-assing'>:</span>",
    "let":"<span class='token-reserved'>let</span>",
    "var":"<span class='token-reserved'>var</span>",
    "const":"<span class='token-reserved'>const</span>",
    "false":"<span class='token-bool'>false</span>",
    "true":"<span class='token-bool'>true</span>",

};

const elems = document.querySelectorAll(".language-javascript");

const initTokenization = () => {
    elems.forEach(el => {
        for(indexName in reserved) {
            el.querySelector("code").innerHTML = el.querySelector("code").innerHTML.replace(indexName, reserved[indexName]);
        }
    });
};

initTokenization();
```

```css
.token-assing {
    color: rgb(255, 212, 132);
}

.token-reserved {
    color: rgb(196, 132, 255);
}

.token-bool {
    color: rgb(255, 132, 132);
}

.token-str {
    color: rgb(132, 255, 138);
}
```

```html
<pre class="language-javascript"><code>let</code></pre>
```